What is the relationship between OR, se, and CI
Apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I have been unable to find a clear answer.
What is the relationship between Odds Ratio, standard error, and confidence intervals?
I try to do a meta-analysis on summary statistics. Some studies report OR + se, and some report OR + CI.
I understand se = (log(CI higher) - log(CI lower)) / 3.92, but I don't understand how I can use the se of the OR to get the CI of the OR. And/or how do I get the se of the logtransformed OR without using the CI?
Doing CI = OR +/- 1.96 * se does not seem to be correct. Or does this only work with log transformed OR?
If I use  se of log OR = se / OR to back compute with Log OR +/- 1.96*se of log OR and exp(CI bounds) I still don't seem to be getting the correct confidence intervals

This relies on the sampling distribution of the log-odds ratio being approximately (the higher the number of events and non-events in both groups, the better the asymptotic approximation gets) normally distributed. Let's call the true log-odds $\theta$ and the estimate of it $\hat{\theta}$. Then
$$\hat{\theta} \sim N(\theta, \hat{\text{SE}}(\hat{\theta})^2).$$
I.e. the estimate log-odds ratio varies around the true value with standard deviation $\hat{\text{SE}}(\hat{\theta})$. On that basis an asymptotic normal-approximation 95% confidence interval for the log-odds ratio is approximately $\hat{\theta} \pm 1.959964 \times \hat{\text{SE}}(\hat{\theta})$.
You get a confidence interval for the odds ratio by using the inverse-logit (aka "standard logistic function", "sigmoid function" or "expit") function. You can back-calculate the limits on the logit scale (and thus the SE on the logit scale) from values on the odds-ratio scale by taking the logit.

Is it correct that se of log OR = se / OR? And I should do Log OR +/- 1.96*se of log OR to get the limits on the logit scale? And I can then backtransform by natural exponential?

@user447683 you do the second of your options
